# unable to convert EditText to int using parseInt

Tags: android, parsing

The logcat shows that the Integer.Parse() function was not able to convert the string to int or float whereas i have linked the xml file in java. Also, i have set the input Type of the rate and quantity column as number so there is no chance that the user can enter anything other than an int or float. Plz help. I have been trying to get this code working for a long time. But i cant find the solution.

Attached is the code:

```
public int initializeVars(){

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        //items[i] is the AutoCompleteTextView array
        item[i]=items[i].getText().toString();
        iquant[i]=Integer.valueOf(quant[i].getText().toString());
        irate[i]=Float.valueOf(rates[i].getText().toString());

        if(item[i]=="")
            break;
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: i can send the logcat screenshot. Let me know if you want. unfortunatly, i dont have enough reputation to post an image

Comment: kindly post the line where u getting error dont put full code

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: i want to get some info from user in a form format having 3 columns (name, quantity and price).

Comment: one more thing, is it advisable to define editText and textView variables in array format like i have done

Comment: You try to convert an empty string into a int, it is expected to receive a numberFormatException, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @StephaneMathis plz correct me if i am wrong using the if statement to terminate the 'for loop'

Comment: there are a total of 9 rows. so for instance when a user enters the details of 3 items, i want to convert that specific data using the function i have given above. Maybe this code is not working properly. Logcat shows numberFormatException, invalid int=""

Comment: You test if the text isn't empty after trying to convert it. You should test it before and do the parse only if it not null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of **valueOf** you can try parsing it directly via

```
yourInt = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
youtFloat = Float.parseFloat(yourString);
```

I always do it this way and it works. In the **float** variable make sure that decimals are marked by "." not ",".

You may also want to try and catch *NumberFormatException* to avoid problems while parsing.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these kind of circumstances use these two functions.

For Int

```
private int getIntFromString(String str){
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For float

```
private float getFloatFromString(String str){
        try{
            return Float.parseFloat(str);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return 0f;
        }
}
```

Call these methods at required places

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `parseInt` method instead of `valueOf` and also keep that parsing code in `try{}...catch{}` block of `NumberFormateException`.

> ```
> try{
>     iquant[i]=Integer.parseInt(quant[i].getText().toString());
>     irate[i]=Float.parseFloat(rates[i].getText().toString());
>     }
>     catch(NumberFormateException e){}
> ```

Comment: i have tried this method also but it doesn't work. BTW i couldn't find the difference between ValueOf() methoid and ParseInt() mehtod.

Answer (score 0):

**INT**

```
try {
    myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
}
```

**FLOAT**

```
try {
    myFloat = Float.parseFloat(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
}
```